# Account address string length always 56?

Tags: accounts, keypair

Modeling DB table. Is the account id (public key) string length always 56 and always will be?

Comment: You can never predict the answer to "always will be?".

Comment: Wait, I'm confused about the edit. Why did you change "account id" to "account address"? As far as I understood the "account address" has the form user*product.com and the "account id" is the public key, no? The public key is defined as "Account ID" here: http://stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/accounts.html @Orbit Lens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's always 56 for the current encoding scheme. And there is no intention to change the keypair generation mechanism in the nearest future, as far as I know.

The invention of the relatively cheap quantum computers with more than 100 qubits may lead to cryptography schemes reconsideration. But they won't be available for at least 2-3 years.

Therefore, you can safely assume that all Stellar addresses will be 56 chars long.

Comment: Thanks but I'm confused about the edit. Why did you change "account id" to "account address"? As far as I understood the "account address" has the form user*product.com and the "account id" is the public key, no? @Orbit Lens

Edit: Following the "Account ID" definition here: https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/accounts.html

And the "Account/Stellar Address" definition here: https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/federation.html

Comment: The two are synonyms. It's just more common to mention "account address" in Stellar.